# angular 2 typescript : concat() work as mutable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am declaring an array on a provider **@Injectable** to use it in different components.

```
  normeList: any[] = [
    {
      name: 'choice 1',
      type:'false'
    },
    {
      name: 'choice 2',
      type:'false'
    }
  ];
```

On the component, I assigned that array like this:

```
this.myArray = [].concat(this.sharedListDeclarationProvider.normeList);
```

on the view, I am working with the `myArray` and I am changing the `type` on the `myArray` from false to true;

the problem is that 'myArray' on the component and `normList` declared on the provider also changing.

How can I change the value of the `myArray` without changing the `normeList`

Comment: What exactly are you trying? You want to copy normeList of your provider to myArray?

Comment: yes without changing normeList if I change the myArray

Comment: See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52699249/3543808) below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume you want to clone the `normeList` array from provider and use it in your component.

If you want to copy the array without mutation or side effects you could use `slice` method of array but this would only works for simple arrays. For complex arrays you can use

- `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array))`
- ES6 version using spread operator [...array] 
  along with map
- combination of `map` with `Object.assign` should work

So for your case you can rewrite the below line

```
this.myArray = [].concat(this.sharedListDeclarationProvider.normeList);
```

with

```
this.myArray = this.sharedListDeclarationProvider.normeList.map(item=>Object.assign({}, item));
```

or even shorter using ES6 spread operator

```
this.myArray = this.sharedListDeclarationProvider.normeList.map(item=>{}..item));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **JSON.parse** and **JSON.stringify**

```
this.myArray = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify((this.sharedListDeclarationProvider.normeList));
```